# Qdate, getting first day of month

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I am writing a weekly schedule for a calendar in PySide (QcalendarWidget). For example, in first week, I want to have tasks A,B,C,D for each day of this week. A dictionary for the first week (first 7 days) of each month is something like this:

```
FirstWeekTasks={1:["A","B"],3:["C","D"],5:["A","D"]}
```

where 1, 3, and 5 are the first, third, and fifth day of the current month.

how can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the dates for the 1, 3, and 5th day of the month?

Comment: @BrendanAbel exactly, In another word, I want for current month, set the tasks. Each week has different Tasks sets.

Comment: What do 1, 3, and 5 mean?do you want the first day of each week? Or month?

Comment: @BrendanAbel for the first week, the 1, 3, 5 stands for the days. For example, 1st day of the week, 3rd day of week, and so on.

Comment: But weeks don't line up with months.  E what if the first day of the month is in the middle of a week

Comment: @BrendanAbel Exactly, that is why I want to find way to work around this problem.

Comment: It's still not clear what dates you want.  Perhaps you could make a small example and show what dates from a month you want

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [QDate.addDays()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdate.html#addDays).

Start with the selected date from the calendar widget:

```
>>> seldate = calwidget.selectedDate()
>>> seldate
PySide.QtCore.QDate(2016, 4, 19)
```

Then to get the required days of the selected calendar month, just subtract the [day()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdate.html#day):

```
>>> seldate.day()    
19
>>> seldate.addDays(1 - seldate.day()) # first
PySide.QtCore.QDate(2016, 4, 1)
>>> seldate.addDays(3 - seldate.day()) # third
PySide.QtCore.QDate(2016, 4, 3)
>>> seldate.addDays(5 - seldate.day()) # fifth
PySide.QtCore.QDate(2016, 4, 5)
```

So `addDays()` can take a positive number to go forwards in time, and a negative number to go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Using `time` module:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.localtime().tm_mday
4
```

Using `datetime` module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().day
4
```